# how to display another field in a lookup column dropdown?

Tags: lookup-column

In MyList I have a lookup column that is populated with values 
from a list with columns ID,DESCRIPTION

When a user inserts a new item the dropdown box only shows ID values.

[image]

I would like to see the DESCRIPTION instead as a user can't remember every ID.

How can I do this?

Comment: List Settings -> Your lookup field -> "In this column:" choose "Description"

Comment: @GintasK Why you didn't add your comment as answer :) , it looks correct answer

Comment: @M.Qassas I didn't quite catch the question as this is too simple, it was just a guess as I thought OP requires both ID & Description in the drop-down :)

Comment: your help try is very appreciated :)

Comment: He wanted to save the ID, the FK, so if the description changed, it would affect the FK relationship. How does one save the ID but present the description?

Comment: @user88945, the lookup relation is always linked to ID field in the back-end. the description field used here is for display purpose. if the description changed, it will auto change in lookup, mapping to same parent item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to list setting
2. Create new column or alter your existing column.
3. Choose type as Lookup
4. Provide your list name from where you want to lookup in *"Get information from:"* drop down.
5. Now choose your **'description'** column in *"In this column:"* drop down and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but that answer is incorrect - Gyonder wants the ID value to be brought across to his list, but he needs to display the description so that he can determine which one he needs.

I have a similar need - I want to get a unique value (ID) from another list, but I need to see the last name, first name and city when selecting the lookup item because the lookup list has multiple people with similar names. I don't want to add those values to my list, but I need to see them to decide which ID I need to select.

It drives me nuts that such a simple requirement has never been available in SharePoint lookups.